# How to remove text from after an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This demo code loops 3 times and every time appends text.
What I need is that text is not get appended but replaced, so that previously appended text should be removed before adding the new one.
I have tried a lot of things, nothing worked.

**EDIT: You can't add an extra tag after the span!**

```
 <div>
     <span id="i_1">this is </span>
</div>
​
var i = 3;
while(i>0)
{
     //// how to remove the text added on the previous iteration?
    $("#i_1").after('text');
    i--;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pHYHW/

Comment: "You can't add an extra tag after the span!" --- is there some **valid** reason behind this requirement? What's wrong with another extra tag (within or after existing `span`)?

Comment: Yes, the valid reason is called **learing**. The point is to learn the  capabilities of jQuery. Adding an extra tag is completely off-topic in this sense.

Comment: learning - is when you can implement something in the most common and straightforward way :-) In this case it is to add another tag. It is the best and the simplest solution, used by everyone. In this case you don't have any chance to select the part of the text whose position cannot be described by selectors (and it cannot be)

Comment: @zerkms Your last comment about learning is just simply wrong. Adding an extra tag is not a solution as you have put it, it is a workaround. See the difference?

Comment: it's not a workaround, it is a solution that everyone uses. And there is no good alternatives (the only upvoted answer is terrible - it is difficult to maintain and difficult to read). But if you're insisting - I don't care, look for some terrible and tricky code, instead of best practice. And good luck ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Ok, now you are talking :) You say that there are no good alternatives, but what if the text is already there and it is not within span tags? So the question is how to remove a text and not how to add one.

Comment: if there is no placeholder tag existing in current layout you could put one by javascript and use it. As simple as `$("#i_1").append('<span class="placeholder"><span>');` Placeholder tag-based solution gives you a lot of freedom about how to operate with itself and its contents

Comment: @zerkms Do not use the word 'put', it is not what we need. What if the html comes from a user? Should I ask the user to 'put' stuff? The question is simple, you have a span with a text after it, how you remove the text?

Comment: can you define "text after it" in a formal way? What is a boundary for  that text? The next tag? Or what?

Comment: does this count http://jsfiddle.net/pHYHW/6/ ?

Comment: Well, it does count, but it is kinda the same as sushil's upvoted answer. This is an ugly way to do it, any better solutions?

Comment: Why don't you just use the appropriate plugin for that? I mean it's jQuery, that's what the *jQuery afterText Plugin* is for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11138498/367456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piece of cake, that's what the ***jQuery afterText Plugin*** is for.

Example/[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLFPU/):

```
<div>
  <span id="i_1">this is </span>
</div>
​
var i = 3;
while (i)
{
    $("#i_1").afterText('text');
    i--;
}
```

[jQuery afterText Plugin on github](https://gist.github.com/2965555/)

Comment: Rocks. Totally does exactly what OP asks for. You think plugins are bad? I suggest you stop using jQuery then, I mean jQuery w/o plugins?

Comment: I had to re-accept. The initially accepted solution was unstable.

Comment: That's what my troll-style comments were about. But some of the criticism is right (that it must not be a jQuery plugin). I'm currently tweaking a hybrid, so you can get best of both worlds.

Comment: what is a hybrid and why a jQuery plugin is bad(giving you put the code NOT in a separate js file)?

Comment: Some might argue invoking `$(...)` for DOM manipulation is just "too much". I'd say, if so, why to use jQuery overall? It's a fair interface especially as `$()` has been invoked already the overhead is not much, plugin or not. By *hybrid* I mean some javascript code that offers the plugin interface *and* javascript interface, e.g. as an object of it's own.

Comment: Here is an updated version, that you can use directly. Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/tLFPU/2/

Comment: Well, sometimes I fall into jQuery library while in debug and the amount of stuff that is being called is so enormous,  that your snippet is hardly a drop in a sea.

Comment: I prefer to use it as a plugin

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 3;
while ( i ) {
    $("#i_1")[ 0 ].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'text';
    i--;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/pHYHW/7/

There you go, enjoy. You can also use `data` instead of `nodeValue` if you prefer.

By the way, this works because `nextSibling` is a `textNode`, thus the `nodeValue` property is available.

Comment: and why exactly you used `$("#i_1")[0]` instead of `document.getElementById('i_1')` ?

Comment: @tereško because there is [tag:jquery], there had to be some!

Comment: Also broken. You can fail with DOM here hard time. I suggest you use the plugin instead. It's there, it works, it's easy.

Comment: @hakre broken? In which way? The jsfiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/pHYHW/7/

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: This works only with very special HTML. You will realize that it's broken at that stage you don't really need the problems because of this bad interfaced non-jQuery-like javascript hack. Believe me, the hurting will be very hard when you don't expect it. HTML can be very tough, and we use jQuery to tame it. If you leave the path of the query, do it on your own risk!

Comment: @hakre OP clearly wants a special case with some special HTML. Of course this answer is specific to his question. Btw, jQuery uses `nodeValue` (recursively) for his `text()` method, so it's quite safe :)

Comment: @RegisteredUser `$('#i_1')` is a jquery object. Its first element (`[0]`) is the first DOM element the selector returned.

Comment: So `$('#i_1') == $('#i_1')[0]` ?

Comment: @RegisteredUser no, `({}).toString.apply($('#notify-container')) === '[object Object]'` while `({}).toString.apply($('#notify-container')[0]) === [object HTMLDivElement]`. The second is the **DOM** element, what you get using `getElementById`, the former is a jQuery object.

Comment: @hakre The copyright text turned me off. It is too long( 1.7KB )

Comment: @RegisteredUser: You can compress if you like a non-source-code form of the work, that's not restricted. I added it: https://gist.github.com/2965555 - It's exactly 161 bytes.

Comment: @Esailija Hello my friend, glad to see you here. Do I miss something, it will be awesome to hear your input!

Comment: @RegisteredUser http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript its where the cool kids hang out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting text after the element, modify the HTML to include an element that holds the text:

```
<span id="i_1">this is </span> <span id="value"></span>
```

And just set the text of the other element:

```
for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    $("#value").text('text');
}
```

Comment: It is no brainier to add another element. The question is how to do it without.

Comment: "The question is how to do it without." --- who said so? I don't see such requirement in the original question. Any **real** reason to follow unobvious way instead of bullet-proof solution?

Comment: @RegisteredUser: there is no mention of this in the question itself.

Comment: @zerkms & Blender: You should have been more intelligent about understanding that whoever posts a question like this, probably already knows about the option of adding an EXTRA tag.

Comment: @Registered User: 1. it's not polite 2. there are users of different levels on SO asking questions, so no one could guess either OP knows about that or not. So it is *always* a good idea to give as much details and requirements so answerers could give the most accurate answer. For now it looks like you just wasted my time and now blaming me in being not intelligent enough.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry for wasting your time man, but despite all your efforts and further clarifications, the question stands open.

Comment: @Registered User: it still doesn't have any additional requirements. Please bother on modifying your question so further readers could get what you want without requirement of reading all the comments (and your mind) and as a result being blamed in lack of intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var i = 3;
var old_text = $('#i_1').html();
while(i>0)
{
    $("#i_1").html(old_text + 'text');
    i--;
}
```

DEMO at: http://jsfiddle.net/2DcXe/
​

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but try this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <span id="i_1">this is </span><span id="i_2"></span>
</div>
```

​

Javascript

```
var i = 3;
while(i>0)
{
    $("#i_2").html('text');
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not jQuery but here is how I would do it...

```
var ele = document.getElementById('i_1'); // get the element
var tn = ele.nextSibling, // get it's next sibling (picks up text nodes)
    mode = 'textContent' in ele ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'; // ( ie is smelly )
for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    tn[mode] = "Text"; // change the text content. 
}
```

[Here is the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/x7xRA/)

Comment: That's broken. Broken! Why don't you want to use the plugin? Nothing to do at all! ^^

Comment: @hakre except annoying dependancy that needs to be managed :P

Comment: Seems to work for me and now I don't need your useless overhead.

Comment: Sure, works for a very special case of HTML element combinations. You say useless overhead? Looks like that this here has already more code then mine, and it still misses the interface.

Comment: @rlemon: Your argumentation smells like premature optimization, and you still fail. You only do this for very special HTML. That's failure. You should better copy from my code to prevent that. You don't need jQuery, try harder to port the plugin to normal javascript. ;)

Comment: @hakre stick to php mate. You are out of your element and just pushing some library.

Comment: @rlemon: As written, I have no problem to port that to javascript. Your code is still not safe btw, so actually, when it comes down to earth - regardless of jQuery or ECMA Script - I would not suggest your solution. All I was saying is that mine is pretty much okay in the context of the question and it's *safe* to use. Something that makes it stand out of the other answers.

Comment: you came into the comments and started flaming all the non-jQuery solutions. i.e. you are trolling. the OP accepted @Florians answer because it likely solved his very unique use case.. which is what we were after. Now do us all a favour and stop.